# Select from table where an entry does not exist in another

Tags: join, crystal-reports

I am sure my title leaves a lot to be desired, but let me try to explain the issue.

I have a table `accounts` like so:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|    id    |   name    |   email   |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|     1    |   Bob     |bob@bob.com|
+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I have a packages table like so:

```
+----------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+
|    id    |package_id | start_date|end_date| acc_id |
+----------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+
|     1    |   15      |2014-01-01 |        |  1     |
+----------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

An account can have multiple packages, though they will not have the same package ie two active packages with an `package_id` of 15.

I need to effectively select all accounts where they do not have an active package with a `package_id` of 15 or 25. I use the following to determine if the package is active:

```
({packages.start_date} >= CurrentDate and ({packages.end_date} <= CurrentDate or {packages.end_date} = DATE(0000,00,00) or ISNULL({packages.end_date})))
```

I have seen where I can say have a second select in the formula, asssign the select a name and then use this value to compare. So for example

```
(select * from packages where ({packages.start_date} >= CurrentDate and ({packages.end_date} <= CurrentDate or {packages.end_date} = DATE(0000,00,00) or ISNULL({packages.end_date}))) AND acc_id = accounts.id AND package_id IN(15,25)) AS has_package
```

The  i can say do:

```
has_package <= 0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where you want this? I think you want in sql server side, why report side? also where are stuck or eror

Comment: @Ajay2707 I need to create this report side for someone else who is not a coder. I am simply stuck at the moment trying to figure this out, I am getting errors as I try different code as expected.

Comment: you want to select only those that doesn't have package id 15 or 25 correct?

Answer (score 0):

In record selection formula write below code:

```
Not(package_id IN(15,25)))
```

Comment: Presumably though if they have say a package with `id` 10 and a package with `id` 15 the result will still show, as although we are filtering against 15 and 25, there is still technically a record that exists?

Comment: There is a record always only thing we are doing is to not picking the record in report.